# Webpack-dev-server not hot reloading

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack-dev-server, webpack-5

We recently upgraded to NodeJS 20, and had to upgrade a bunch of other things.
We updated from vue/cli-service 4 -> 5 and from Webpack 4 -> 5, which changed our webpack-dev-server to v4

The problem we are facing is running our dev server via vue-cli-service serve.
It starts up fine with no errors on port 8888, and when we make changes to a .vue file it says:

> WAIT  Compiling...
> 3:14:59 PM
>
> Compiling...
>
> DONE  Compiled successfully in 590ms
> 3:15:00 PM
>
> App running at:
>
> - Local:   http://localhost:8888/
> - Network: http://localhost:8888/

The main problem is that when I visit the page that I changed on port 8888 locally, it doesn't show the change. This all worked correctly before the upgrade. I followed the webpack-dev-server migration guide and I believe I corrected everything. I'm including the before and after of my vue.config.js files.

Here are my config files.

webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
    
    module.exports = {
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
              'vue-style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader',
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      mode: 'development',
    
      plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
        }),
      ],
    
    };
```

vue.config.js (pre-migration, webpack-dev-server 3.x.x)

```
const path = require('path');
const WebpackAssetsManifest = require('webpack-assets-manifest');
const packageJSON = require('./package.json');
const outputDirectory = `target/classes/dist/${packageJSON.name}/vue`;

module.exports = {
  assetsDir: 'static',
  lintOnSave: true,
  // Use a relative path for assets
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/vue/' : '/',

  outputDir: outputDirectory,
  productionSourceMap: false,
  transpileDependencies: ['vue-resource'],
  devServer: {

    proxy: {
      '/': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8081/', // this configuration needs to correspond to the Spring Boot backends' application.properties server.port
        ws: true,
        changeOrigin: true,
      },
    },

    disableHostCheck: true,
    writeToDisk: true,
    port: 8888,
    contentBase: [
      path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    ],
  },
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.optimization.splitChunks({
      chunks: 'all',
    });

    // Register the webpack-assets-manifest plugin to generate an asset manifest
    config
      .plugin('assets-manifest')
      .use(WebpackAssetsManifest);
  },
  css: {
    extract: {
      filename: 'css/[name].css',
    },
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    output: {
      filename: 'js/[name].js',
    },
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      },
    },

  },
};
```

vue.config.js (post-migration, webpack-dev-server 4.x.x)

```
const path = require('path');
const WebpackAssetsManifest = require('webpack-assets-manifest');
const packageJSON = require('./package.json');
const outputDirectory = `target/classes/dist/${packageJSON.name}/vue`;

module.exports = {
  assetsDir: 'static',
  lintOnSave: true,
  // Use a relative path for assets
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/vue/' : '/',

  outputDir: outputDirectory,
  productionSourceMap: false,
  transpileDependencies: ['vue-resource'],
  devServer: {
    port: 8888,
    proxy: {
      '/': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8081/', // this configuration needs to correspond to the Spring Boot backends' application.properties server.port
        ws: true,
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        logLevel: 'debug',
      },
    },
    allowedHosts: 'all',
    devMiddleware: {
      index: false,
      writeToDisk: true,
    },
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, 'public/'),
    },
    open: { // Opens browser in incognito mode
      app: {
        name: 'chrome',
        arguments: ['--incognito'],
      },
    },
  },
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.optimization.splitChunks({
      chunks: 'all',
    });

    // Register the webpack-assets-manifest plugin to generate an asset manifest
    config
      .plugin('assets-manifest')
      .use(WebpackAssetsManifest);
  },
  css: {
    extract: {
      filename: 'css/[name].css',
    },
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    output: {
      filename: 'js/[name].js',
    },
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Delete `webpack.config.js` and fix the warning by adding `:key` prop to the items with `v-for` applied.

Comment: The warnings are gone, but it did not fix the hot reloading problem

Comment: Do you see errors related to WebSocket in the browser console ?

Comment: I don't get any errors when I move from port 8081 (tomcat server) to port 8888 (webpack-dev-server)

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
I tried many configurations, and adding this to the devMiddleware worked:

```
devMiddleware: {
  publicPath: "/",
  index: true,
  writeToDisk: true,
},
```

Adding the publicPath and changing index to `true` did the trick. Thanks everyone!

Comment: I don't use `devMiddleware` at all with Vue-CLI v5 and I still have HMR working. Perhaps there is something else in your setup that breaks the HMR.